# Android thread finished callback

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity, android-asynctask

I want execute http post after getting response from server.
If server response is false the http post will execute else not execute.
How can i do for this.

My android main activity code:

```
if (Utility.isValidMobile(mobileNumber)) {
            String isAvailable = userDelegate.checkUser(mobileNumber, context);


            if (isAvailable.equals("false")) {
                userDelegate.addUser(userMO, context);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your mobile number is" + mobileNumber + "name is" + userName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (isAvailable.equals("true")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your mobile number is already registerd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

when i click signup button this above code will executed

My Userdelegate class code :

```
public void addUser(final UserMO userMo, final Context context) {

    final String jsonStringObject = gson.toJson(userMo);

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare(); // for the child Thread
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
                                                                                    // Limit
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userBO", jsonStringObject));
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.101:8080/warname/user/addUser");
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                Toast.makeText(context, "Your user id " + rd.readLine(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Looper.loop(); // Loop in the message queue
        }
    };
    t.start();

}

public void getMatchingExistingUserList(final String mobile_number, final Context context) {

    final String jsonStringObject = gson.toJson(mobile_number);

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare(); // for the child Thread
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
                                                                                    // Limit
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userBO", jsonStringObject));
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.101:8080/warname/user/addUser");
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                final String responseString = rd.readLine();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Looper.loop(); // Loop in the message queue
        }
    };
    t.start();
}

public String checkUser(final String mobile_number, final Context context) {

    final StringBuilder isAvailable = new StringBuilder();

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override   
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare(); // for the child Thread
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("MobileNumber", gson.toJson(mobile_number)));
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.101:8080/warname/user/checkUserMobileNumber");
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
                isAvailable.append(rd.readLine());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Looper.loop(); // Loop in the message queue
        }
    };
    t.start();
    return isAvailable.toString();
}
```

Problem is i got response false but the if condition not working.
how to solve this problem.

After changing:

```
if (Utility.isValidMobile(mobileNumber)) {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    return userDelegate.checkUser(mobileNumber, context);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String isAvailable) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), isAvailable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (isAvailable.equals("false")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your mobile number is" + mobileNumber + "name is" + userName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        userDelegate.addUser(userMO, context);
                    } else if (isAvailable.equals("true")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your mobile number is already registerd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }.execute(null, null, null);
        }
```

The if condition is not working ?

Comment: is it giving any error? and what is value of this `isAvailable.equals("false")`

Comment: But isAvailable value is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If server response is false the http post will execute else not
>   execute. How can i do for this

Issue occurring because you are using Threads in `checkUser` and `addUser`. Thread's execute with-out stopping execution of current Thread.

For example, when `checkUser` method is called from main thread then `final StringBuilder isAvailable = new StringBuilder();` executing on main thread and Thread `t` is executing in separately. so system return control to next line which is `return isAvailable.toString();` without waiting Thread execution complete means `checkUser` method  always return `null` or `empty` string.

Same is for `addUser` method.

To do task accoding to result of `checkUser` method response use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class.

Comment: @nmkkannan: ok do it your self then i will sure try to help you

Comment: @nmkkannan: what problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using new threads to do http request here. Therefore your delegate methods are not synchronized. `addUser` and `checkUser` will return before your http requests finish.

To write multi thread codes like yours, you may want to use a some kind of a listener to do the threads communication work.

For example, you can pass a listener to your delegate which looks like this

```
class Listener{
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    public void onUserAdded(){
         handler.post(new Runnable(){
               public void run(){
                     // Toast your thing
               }
         });
    }

    public void onUserChecked(final boolean available){
         handler.post(new Runnable(){
               public void run(){
                     if(available){
                           // Toast your thing
                     }else{
                          userDelegate.addUser(userMO, context);
                     }
               }
         });
    }
}
```

And all your `new Thread(){ run(){` codes should end with all call to the listener.

As you can see I use a Handler to post works back to the UI thread. This is very important for you to notify your UI elements of what is going on in your none-UI threads.

Also, I can't see what you are doing with your `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()`. No child thread is there.